# Why are applications closing in GNOME Classic when I minimise them?

Tags: 11.10

New to Linux and have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 secured.  Am running Gnome Classic menu but notice that my applications are CLOSING when I minimize them.  Can anyone tell me how to correct this?

Comment: Maybe you should clarify how you are minimizing them... are you clicking on a button?  Using a command or keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're clicking on the wrong button, then you can correct it by clicking the right one. Literally. In Windows, the close-button is to the right and the minimize button is to the left. Since Ubuntu has those controls on the left side of the window, the close button is to the left and the minimize-button is to the right.

Is it possible you're just clicking the wrong button? It's the only immediate explanation I can think of.